# Community Cloud!

Tags: lightning-community, community-cloud, experience-cloud

I created a community site in a sandbox and I created another sandbox because of some technical problems, now my question is, is there a way to migrate my community side to the new sandbox without attempting to build it from scratch again!
Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrate_changesets.htm&type=0)?

Comment: Yeah! This solves my problem, here is the full doc https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_migrate_changesets.htm&type=5